# Mesh to Empty Object

Tags: mesh, game-engine, objects

I am looking for a way to convert mesh object to an empty object. I need to keep all the game variables, assigned logic, but remove the visual mesh data. How do I do it?

Comment: Can you explain a little more in depth why you want to do this? There are options, but they may not address what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: do you want a character's mesh to disappear but have the logic of the character remain, as if the character was replaced by an empty? you can use the edit object actuator, set to replace mesh, and replace with an empty mesh. Or, if you do not mean during run time, add an empty, select it and your other object, and copy game property to selected, copy logic bricks to selected.

Comment: The second version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible.

But you can create an empty mesh and copy all the attributes from the other object. Certain attributes can be copied with the add-on `3D View:Copy Attribute Menu`. You can use <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> to open the copy menu.

Comment: All attributes means also game logic? If so, than this is it:)

Comment: Copying game logic and game properties is enabled by default. You need the mentioned add-on to copy other attributes like location/orientation.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into edit mode and delete all vertices you will still retain the object origin.  I don't know if it will retain all the game variables, assigned logic.